# Field extension of fixed field has degree greater than the size of the group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $G\leqslant\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ a (finite) group, and $K^G$ the fixed subfield of $K$.
How exactly would you go about proving the following?$$[K:K^G]\geqslant|G|$$

For some reason I have come to a complete blank trying to even start on this!
I would much prefer some hints to a complete solution, but either is appreciated.

**Edit:**
Sorry, just saw that this hint is at the bottom of the question:
*You may assume that if $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ are distinct field homomorphisms from $K$ to $L$ then $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ is linearly independent over $L$.*

Comment: Can you use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Comment: I would assume so (I just have the question from a past exam paper taken out of context). I would also be interested in hearing a method without using it though, if a reasonably simple one exists.

Comment: I take from the hint that you are not supposed to use the fundamental theorem, nor Artin's theorem.  So I don't think an answer has yet been provided that is what they are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I abbreviate $F=K^G$. Let $n=[K:F]$. Consider the set $V$ of $F$-linear mappings from $K$ to itself. The $V$ has the usual structure of a vector space over $F$, and clearly has dimension $n^2$, after all $V$ is isomorphic to the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$.

But $V$ also has a structure of a vector space over $K$. Just multiply the values by scalars from $K$ instead of restricting yourself to $F$ (this works only because the range, here $K$, already has multiplication by elements of $K$ defined.

What is the dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $K$? Call it $m$. The same argument that you have seen when proving the product formula in a tower of field extensions shows that
$$
n^2=\dim_FV=[K:F]\dim_KV=nm.
$$
This implies that $m=n$.

It sounds like you want to think about the rest (great!), so I spoilerize the rest (mouseover the pale pink block to see the text).

> The Lemma in your hint exhibits a set of $|G|$ elements of $V$ that are linearly independent over $K$. Basic linear algebra tells us that the size of a linearly independent set is bounded from above by the dimension of the space. Therefore

$$
|G|\le \dim_KV=n=[K:F].
$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: When $K/K^G$ is (later in your text) proven to be a Galois extension, you get a corollary stating that $G$ is also a basis of $V$ over $K$.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I don't mean to be cheeky, but there's a later question that asks to show that this bound is attained if $G$ acts faithfully on $K$. The proof that we've been given of this fact is quite long and uses the Rank-Nullity theorem and things like that. Is there a neater way of getting that result now using this proof that you've just provided?

Comment: Actually, in this proof, when you say that we have $|G|$ linearly independent elements of $V$, aren't you assuming that $G$ acts faithfully?

Comment: Yes. I assumed that the elements of $G$ are distinct. Was that not among the assumptions? If so, then this is wrong.

Comment: But wait a second! You can have a very large normal subgroup acting trivially. There's no way the result would be true, if we don't assume that the action is faithful.

Comment: Maybe I am getting confused about what faithful actions are. But we have a proof of another theorem that says 'If a finite group $G$ acts faithfully on a field $L$ then $[L:L^G]=|G|$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23463/discussion-between-tim-and-jyrki-lahtonen).